# Laravel 5.8 access new row ID during creating method

Tags: laravel-5.8

My `User` Class uses a Trait which creates tables on  behalf of a new user registered.

I want to access the new user `id` number to use it in the table naming like below (which does not work).

```
static::creating(function($obj)
{
    if (empty($obj->db_name)) {
        $obj->attributes['table_id'] = 'user_' . $obj->id;
    }
});
```

How can I access the `id` of this new user during the `creating` process so I can create and save the record without going back using `created` method to update the column.

Answer (score 1):

`creating` occurs *before* the record is saved - it has no ID yet. You may want to hook into the `created` event instead, which occurs *after* the record has been saved and has an ID.